# Combining React and React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, barcode

I have a question regarding combining elements of React in React-native app.
Could something like this be possible?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text, 
    View,
    Image,
    ListView,
    Switch,
    TextInput,
    AsyncStorage,
    BackAndroid,
    Navigator, 
    TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';  

var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Barcode = require('react-barcode');


class Third extends React.Component { 
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Barcode value="http://github.com/kciter" />,
        mountNode 
    );
};
```

I am asking this because i have trouble finding barcode generator module for react-native. Any suggestions?

Thank you for all the replies, 
Domen

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-barcode

Comment: barcode doesnt equal qr and aztec code

Comment: Ohh, I see. You are looking for 1-D barcode

Comment: quick google search resolved this: https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner

Comment: this is only for reading, not generating from scanned barcodes

Comment: i did my research...

Comment: What type of barcode do you want to generate?

Comment: As @Gosha said. React and react-native are two different environments. After running command "react-native run-ios" your code will be compiled to the native IOS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not possible. React Native environment uses native components under the hood, not the actual DOM, so you can't simply use React components in this environment and call it a day.

Your best shot is to look for native alternatives.

---

You could *theoretically* create a native component, which will create a web view, and render its children in that view. You will need to use the *private* `ReactMultiChild` API — in fact, this is what React components use to allow rendering on things other than DOM, like canvas.

For example, [react-canvas](https://github.com/Flipboard/react-canvas) does it, I also did it myself on [my side project](https://github.com/goshakkk/pabla), also with canvas. It looks like this:

```
<Canvas>
  <CanvasRect frame={[10, 10, 20, 20]} color="black" />
</Canvas>
```

In this example, `CanvasRect` is going to be rendered by `Canvas` onto a canvas element, not the actual DOM.

So it is by all means possible to bridge several renderers together. For your use case, going ground-up and creating a bridge like that for web components in React Native might be an overkill though.

*(Edit: I've wrote [a post on custom React renderers](http://goshakkk.name/react-custom-renderers/). While it does not touch React Native, the approach is quite general.)*

Answer (score 1):

What you need essentially is a mapping from the react-native components to react components (actual DOM Object). [React-Native-Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) does just that. You can nest the components of the React and React-Native.

e.g.

```
<ScrollView>
 <div>Hello World</div>
</ScrollView>
```

This code will transform and will create actual DOM (not the prettiest one but does the job). Currently, it does not support mapping for all the components but supports most of them.

React-Native-Web heavily depends on the [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). So make sure you have a good understanding of [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) before you get into it.